# HAProxy redirect scheme in backend not working

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I have a haproxy cluster with two frontends for http and https and many backends which are selected using a domain2backend map.

Some of the backends must be accessed only through HTTPS.

I tried using `redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }` in those backends but haproxy seems to be ignoring it. I even tried simply to redirect (without any condition) but haproxy ignores the redirect in the backend section.

Configuration excerpt:

```
global
    maxconn 1024
    debug
    log localhost local0 debug
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    balance roundrobin
    maxconn 32
    log global
    monitor-uri /haproxy_test
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    option httplog
    option forwardfor
    use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_dom(./etc/domain2backend.map)]

frontend https-in
    bind *:4443 ssl crt ./etc/ssl
    mode http
    option httplog
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_dom(./etc/domain2backend.map)]

backend app1_www
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server localhost:3000 127.0.0.1:3000 check

backend app2_www
    redirect scheme https
    server localhost:3000 127.0.0.1:3000 check
```

Neither app1_www nor app2_www redirects work.

I am using HA-Proxy version 1.7.3 2017/02/28

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After many attempts and thanks to the helpful community at http://discourse.haproxy.org I found the solution:

It is necessary to specify `mode http` in the backend to allow the redirections to work.

The variable ssl_fc is available in the backend so it is possible to use the condition `if !{ ssl_fc}` like in the following code sample:

```
backend app1_www
    mode http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server localhost:3000 127.0.0.1:3000 check
```